# Javascript regex for matching twitter-like hashtags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like some help on figuring out the JS regex to use to identify "hashtags", where they should match all of the following:

1. The usual twitter style hashtags: `#foobar`
2. Hashtags with text preceding: `abc123#xyz456`
3. Hashtags with *space* in them, which are denoted as: `#[foo bar]` (that is, the [] serves as delimiter for the hashtag)

For 1 and 2, I was using something of the following form:

```
var all_re =/\S*#\S+/gi;
```

I can't seem to figure out how to extend it to 3. I'm not good at regexps, some help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So it has to match either all non-space characters or any characters between (and including) `[` and `]`:

```
\S*#(?:\[[^\]]+\]|\S+)
```

Explanation:

```
\S*                # any number of non-white space characters
#                  # matches #
(?:                # start non-capturing group
    \[             # matches [
    [^\]]+         # any character but ], one or more
    \]             # matches ]
    |              # OR
    \S+            # one or more non-white space characters
)                  # end non-capturing group
```

**Reference**: [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), [negated character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: Thanks felix. I'm trying this at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html with the Regexp as "\S*#(?:\S+|\[[^\]]+\])" and the string as "this is #[foo bar]". The "Show match" button says "#[foo" - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah it seems you have to reverse the order because `\S+` is more general than `\[...`, so it will always match. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the explanation!

Comment: See this fiddle: http://regexr.com/3bevj, I'm trying to make it NOT find blank space before #tag, and not find #tag inside a URL or when proceeded with non-whitespace i.e. number or slash. `/(#[a-z\d]+)/g`.

Comment: @FelixKling your regex works very well in most cases. Thanks for sharing How would you suggest handling situations where a # appears in the middle of some text like, "the#tag" so that only "#tag" is matched?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var all_re =/(\S*#\[[^\]]+\])|(\S*#\S+)/gi;
```

Comment: This also works, I'm accepting Felix's though for the explanation. Thanks xiaowl!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but only want to match when a string starts and ends with the hashtag. So similar problem, hopefully someone else can have use of my solution.

This one matches "#myhashtag" but not "gfd#myhashtag" or "#myhashtag ".

`/^#\S+$/`

`^  #start of regex

\S #Any char that is not a white space

+  #Any number of said char

$  #End of string`

Simple as that.