# Capture emoji in iOS regex

Tags: ios, regex, emoji, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to write an `NSRegularExpression` to capture valid Instagram hashtags. Instagram appears to support 0-9, case insensitive a-z, and _ in their hashtags (you can check validity by visiting https://instagram.com/explore/hashtag-to-check), underscores, and emoji. Capturing the first bit I've mentioned is easy, just `[0-9a-zA-Z_]+`, but I don't know how to incorporate emoji into it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846975/javascript-regex-for-matching-twitter-like-hashtags

Comment: That handles things that I don't want to include, like dashes, dots, and other punctuation.

Comment: Was able to retrofit the answer from that question though, ended up with `#([^[:punct:]|\s]|_)+`